# CodeIgniter View

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Não estou conseguindo apresentar dados na `View`.

Model banco

```
class ModelBanco extends CI_Model
{
    public $em;
    public $senha;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function get_user(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_user');
        $this->db->where('email','magno');
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
}
```

WelcomeController

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
   public function index()  { 
        $this->load->model('ModelBanco','',TRUE);
        $data['query']= $this->ModelBanco->get_user();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
   }
}
```

Welcome_message `View`

```
<html>    
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>    
 </body>    
</html>
```

Banco de dados foi configurado no arquirvo /config/database

```
host='localhost';
username='root';
password='';
database='bd_imobiliaria';
```

A tabela dentro do banco é `tb_user` e campo `email varchar(255)`, existe um registro com o dado "magno". Gostaria de apresentar os registros na tela com codeigniter em **MVC** apenas para teste. Acrescentei na minha `View` o trecho de código sugerido.

```
echo $query->email;
```

Mas esta aparecendo este erro.

> @rray   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/welcome_message.php
>
> Line Number: 69
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_imobiliaria\application\views\welcome_message.php
>   Line: 69 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_imobiliaria\application\controllers\Welcome.php
>   Line: 27 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_imobiliaria\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Já fiz algumas pesquisas sobre `non-object`.

Answer (score 2):

Para exibir corretamente o registro na *view*, fique atento ao nome dado em `$data` pois o nome dessa chave se transformará em uma variável.

```
$data['query']= $this->ModelBanco->get_user();
```

Na *view* chame:

```
<?php echo $query[0]->email; ?>
```

Ou mude o *model* para retornar apenas uma linha com [row()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

```
function get_user(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_user');
    $this->db->where('email','magno');
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

Na *view*:

```
<?php echo $query->email; ?>
```

Comment: Executei a sugestão mas ainda aparece um erro na view, o "erro" esta no proprio codigo em cima. Pesquisei sobre "Trying to get property of non-object", entendi que minha propriedade get da classe model não é um objeto, cheguei a testar um foreach para percorrer a 'query' mas tambem sem resultado.

Comment: @MagnoMalkut no index, faça: `print_r($this->ModelBanco->get_user());`

Comment: A conexao com o banco esta funcionando. resultado:"Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_user] => 1 [email] => magno [senha] => 12345 [user_session_id] => [user_permissions] => ) )"

Comment: @MagnoMalkut, edite a resposta agora.

Comment: Com base na sua sugestão, fiz algo que funcionou:         $query= $this->db->get('tb_user');
 foreach ($query->result() as $row){
  echo $row->email;
 }, mas a minha dúvida é, desta forma eu não estou usando o controller?

Comment: @MagnoMalkut, o `row()` retorna apenas uma linha, o `result()` retorna mais de uma, por isso você precisa do foreach.

Comment: Pesquisei em alguns exemplos, e vi que é bastante comum a view se comunicar com o model diretamente, pelo MVC é correto?

Comment: A view recebe o model geralmente, mas a view não se comunica com o model diretamente, quem faz essa comunicação  entre os dois é o controller. @MagnoMalkut

Comment: OK, entendi a explicação. Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço a todos que me ajudaram, vou postar o resultado.

**Model**

```
function get_user()
{  
        $this->db->select ('*')->from('tb_user');  
        $sql= $this->db->get();  
        $post =array();  
        foreach ($sql->result() as $row){  
            $post[$row->id_user] = $row->email;  
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() 
{  
    $this->load->model('modelbanco','',TRUE);  
    $data['post']= $this->modelbanco->get_user();  
    $this->load->view('welcome_message.php',$data);  
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($post as $id_user =>$email) : ? >   
<?php echo $email; ? > (ID: < ?php echo $id_user; ? >)   
<?php endforeach; ? >
```